# How to get a method called after all multitouch events in render loop are fired?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uikit

I am creating a multitouch iOS toy where user slides fingers over the screens and triggers various animations when passing over 'widgets'.

I have empty spaces between widgets, but I want every touch to make something happen. Therefore I catch touches in a root UIView, and find closest widget for each touch, instead of using each widget's touch handlers (which only work within it's frame).

To do that, I listen on `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`, and find closest widget for each touch. Then this widget keeps touches assigned to it, and an animation plays when that count changes from `0` (= at least one finger is in an area closest to object) or back to `0` (all fingers left).

My problem is, that when for example a finger drags out of widget's area in `touchesMoved` (= `touchCount--`) while another finger is just placed there in `touchesBegan` (= `touchCount++`), two animatons (leave and enter) get triggered, even though the final state is that there was 1 finger before this render loop and there is 1 finger at the end, so nothing should happen.

For this though, I would need some event to fire during every render loop after all multitouch handlers are called, so that I could keep a previous and current touchCount for each widget, and fire animation only for widgets where touchCount changed.

Is there a way to get such a method call? Or, could I expect that for example if I get a method called in every render loop, that all `touches*` methods for this frame were already called?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just leverage the `layoutSubviews` method? It's called after touch interaction was processed. Or you could just throw a block into the main thread run loop and it should get executed after all touches.

Comment: @fluidsonic to get `layoutSubviews` called, I'd need to call `setNeedsLayout` and that seems to be really expensive (unnecessary layout pass when nothing changed). I'll check out the idea with the block in runloop, thanks!

Comment: `setNeedsLayout`, exactly. And layouting an empty `UIView` doesn't really cost anything. I think it can even be done without adding the view to the view hierarchy.